# how do I install python2 on centos 9 stream?

Tags: centos, python-2.x

I am trying to figure out how to install python2 on centos9 stream. I am getting the errors below. Any suggestions?

```
sudo dnf install python2

Last metadata expiration check: 0:04:48 ago on Thu 24 Feb 2022 01:43:10 PM EST.

No match for argument: python2

Error: Unable to find a match: python2
```

Comment: CentOS 9 Stream is based on "Stable Fedora", currently Fedora 35, which has "no python2" but **two** packages: {python2.7 (no python2.7-devel), python2-cairo}. Reason:  python2.7 had *End Of Life* two years ago. ..... ( Fedora still have these two packages because of a couple of old applications.) Ref. https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/35/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/p/

Comment: ok, if you can answer "you can't" I will mark this as the answer and give you credit.

Comment: You could try Python2 Docker image, but still, any modern Python script should be using Python3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to install python2 on centos9 stream

You cannot do that from any repo. No available repo / no packages.

Reason: python2.7 had End Of Life two years ago.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can, using this method:

If you cannot find a package for your distribution (and you probably should be able to), you can download a single-file executable "AppImage" containing Python 2.7 and the standard library. Just download the file, make it executable, rename it "python2" or create a symlink of that name pointing to the AppImage file, and put it in /usr/local/bin/, and getmail will happily run with it.

For example, on an x86_64 Linux system, you could:

```
wget https://github.com/niess/python-appimage/releases/download/python2.7/python2.7.18-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.AppImage
sudo install -m 755 python2.7.18-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.AppImage /usr/local/bin/
sudo ln -sr /usr/local/bin/python2.7.18-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.AppImage /usr/local/bin/python2
```

Source: https://pyropus.ca/software/getmail/documentation.html#python3